# Is there a way to load a specific frame from a website to an iPhone app?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, uiwebview, xml-parsing, xcode4.5

I'm really new to xcode and objective-c. overall fairly new to programming. 
Is there a way to load only a specific frame from a website onto a `UIWebView` on xcode?

I have a website that I need to load onto the app, but the website has different sections to it (it has a calendar, a list of events, and some extra info). Right now I'm loading it into a  `UIWebView`, but the website looks too crowded, so I need to load only the list of events section. I know the website uses plone, but again, I'm not exactly sure what that is.

Would I have to parse the XML and load it into a table view, or is there a way to use `UIWebView` and only load part of the website?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the URL of the frame’s contents, just pass that in as the `UIWevView`’s URL.

**Update:** I thought you were talking about html `<frame>` tags, which would work with the above solution. However, if you mean you want to extract a specific `<div>` from a site, that is going to be much more complicated.

Comment: yeah, I'm talking about the `<div>`.. any tips on what I could do?